# Change CSS and HTML in Total JS Flow

Tags: total.js

I'm working with Total js Flow. I can't in any way modify the CSS and the tags in HTML files as the library every time the app is runnning regenerates the folder 'tmp' that contains all the files served on browser, not allowing the change if not trying to change the flow directly from internal library. On the documentation (brief and confusing) I didn't find anything about it on any setting to use. Does anyone know how to proceed?
Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify [Total.js Flow](https://www.totaljs.com/flow/) easily. Just edit source-code in `source` directory (https://github.com/totaljs/flow) and build your own `flow.package` via `make.sh` or follow the steps below:

- install [Total.js framework](https://www.totaljs.com) as a global module `$ npm install -g total.js`
- open terminal or command-line
- find a directory with source-code `$ cd`/flow/source/`
- create a package `$ tpm create flow.package`
- move `flow.package` to your app
- done

> Read documentation about packages:
>   https://docs.totaljs.com/latest/en.html#pages~Packages~(creating-a-package)

Comment: Thanks! I'm stuck in a similar place but unable to understand how to really 'run' this project to start modifying the source code https://github.com/totaljs/flow